# Tor browser bundle - Vidalia is missing but appears to be working?

Tags: tor

So essentially until yesterday, when I ran the tor browser bundle, vidalia would pop up, connect and do its thing, and then a minute or so later the special tor-firefox browser would pop up with torcheck saying I'm in.

Now vidalia just doesn't appear, and tor-firefox comes up saying I'm okay anyway. I know vidalia is just like a GUI type thing (correct me if I'm wrong, I did also install tor via get-apt install tor).
Should I care that vidalia isnt popping up or no? also, how should I go about getting it back

Comment: You probably shouldn't care. Does the icon appear in the systray when you start it? It should look like an onion.

Comment: No, the onion doesn't show up. Neither system tray nor the normal pop up window.

Comment: Weird. What is the output of running the start-tor-browser script from the terminal? (Use cd path/to/the/folder/the/script/is/in/relative/to/home/folder to get there, and then run ./start-tor-browser)

Comment: Going into the tor browser file and manually selecting the vidalia app, it starts and gives the error "Vidalia detected that tor software exited unexpectedly" upon trying to connect to tor.

Comment: Message log starting w/ first warning "Jul 31 20:28:39.942 [Warning] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Jul 31 20:28:39.942 [Notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jul 31 20:28:39.943 [Notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jul 31 20:28:39.943 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Jul 31 20:28:39.944 [Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above."

Comment: try running killall -9 tor; killall -9 vidalia; and then trying again.

Comment: if I do the ./start-tor browser it only goes 1 line "Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/ubuntu/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US" then I get a pop-up "vidalia has connected to a running tor process the requires a password. Please enter the control password

Comment: That sounds like an issue. I take it you never set a tor password? You may have to redownload.

Comment: after performing killall on both and retrying the ./start-tor browser, the terminal kind of just hangs at "Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/ubuntu/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US" and eventually the tor-firefox browser opens saying I'm connected. Am I right in thinking that essentially tor is operating correctly w/o vidalia? Do I even need vidalia? No I never set a tor password, but like I said I both installed tor via apt-get install tor and then downloaded the tor browser bundle

Answer (score 2):

Newer Tor Browser bundles integrate the functionality of Vidalia in Torbutton, a browser extension for Firefox. A standalone vidalia window won't show up. Instead, it looks like this:

[image]